# Recommend keywords based on past keywords searched

Tags: algorithm, recommendation-engine

I am trying to recommend users the conferences and keywords (which each conferences have) based on what keywords he has searched for.
I am not getting as to which recommender algorithm will be useful for me.

To clarify a bit more:
- When user searches in a search bar, I am taking the search query and doing stop words removal on that, then whitespace segmentation and then on each individual word obtained, I perform stemming. Hence, I will be able to find the topics of the conferences user is interested in.
- I am thinking of creating a user vector which will have all the keywords he is interested in or he has searched for.
- Also, I have list of all the topics of the available conferences in my database.

So, my question is using this user vector what kind of recommender will be userful which will help to recommend topics the user might be interested in. The user has NOT provided any kind of ratings to his liking for the conference topics, since we are extracting the data from the search.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? If you're going to recommend based on previous searches, then you need to save his searches. After that, what do you want to do? You need to provide a lot more information before we can make any intelligent suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Jim for getting back. I have added some more description. Hope this might help you to understand my question properly.

Answer (score 1):

If the only information you have is what the user searched for, then the simplest thing to do is recommend topics based on the topics that others who have searched for the same things have searched for.

For example, Joe searches for *fried green tomatoes* and *purple gummi worms*. If Sam then searches for *purple gummi worms*, then you might recommend he also look at *fried green tomatoes*.

Of course, this model doesn't work well if you only have a handful of participants. But if you have many people searching you can say, based on your analysis of previous searches, that if somebody searches for X, then there is a high probability that he'll search for Y.

This is broadly known as [Collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering).

Comment: Is it the same algorithm used by online vendors (like Amazon) to suggest products to its visitors under the heading "People who bought this also bought" ?

Comment: @gargankit: It's the same concept, yes.

Comment: @Jim: Thank you. I got your point. But, in my system each user is independent. So, Joe might have different interests than Jim. So, what I want to try is - I have list of topics for all the conferences and if there is any topic which user is searching for, then I want to recommend the user with all those keywords which comes in that group. For an instance, if you are looking for HTML and in my list I have CSS or Javascript or Web Development, then I want to recommend all those topics. So, my primary task would be to group all those related topics and I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I also tried to find the group of related technical keywords on the web, but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

In absence of any other metric/rating given by the user, all you've got is the search strings submitted.

Here you could use Frequent itemset mining followed by Association rule generation which should give you a good recommendation in form of frequently co-occuring items(search strings) from all of the history.

You could read more about it here - [Association rule mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning)

Comment: Thanks. But, I would definitely have the topics in a way the user is searching for, since based on that only I am making a user profile. But, the problem is how to find related topics from my list and recommend that. Because from user profile, I can take the keywords one by one and perform the SQL query directly.